# Output XML tags using sprintf

Tags: php, xml

I have a few XML templates that I am trying to fill using PHP's sprintf (v.5.3.8-Win54); however, I noticed that sprintf seems to be having problems with the **<** character. **It seems that the** < **character needs to be followed by a space in order for sprintf to output it correctly.**  I looked at the [PHP sprintf documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) but I couldn't find any references to any special character besides **%**. I echoed the following examples using `echo sprintf($format1, $name, $age);` to show the problem:

```
$name = 'Lame';
$age = 1000;
$format1 = 'My name is %s. I am %d years old.';
$format2 = '<name> %s </name><age> %d </age>';
$format3 = 'name> %s /name>age> %d /age>';
$format4 = '<name %s </name<age %d </age';
$format5 = '<name> %s </name><age> %d </age>';
```

The formats are echoed as:

```
FORMAT 1: My name is Lame. I am 1000 years old.  
FORMAT 2: Lame 1000  
FORMAT 3: name> Lame /name>age> 1000 /age>  
FORMAT 4:   
FORMAT 5: <name> Lame </name><age> 1000 </age>
```

*FORMAT 4 does indeed come out as blank.

Any ideas why the ***<*** character isn't being output unless there is a space following it? I suppose I could just add a space to all the ***<*** characters in the XML templates using find/replace, but I rather find out why this is happening to begin with.  I have a feeling this is going to be basic knowledge that I just haven't come across yet; if so, can you please provide references to any documentation?

***INTERESTING:*** I had to add a space after the ***<*** character while typing out this question in the Stackoverflow interface so that it would appear correctly in the FORMAT 5 line!  Huuuuuuh??!

*** COMPLETE CODE ***

```
<?php   
$name = 'Lame';
$age = 1000;
$format1 = 'My name is %s. I am %d years old.';
$format2 = '<name> %s </name><age> %d </age>';
$format3 = 'name> %s /name>age> %d /age>';
$format4 = '<name %s </name<age %d </age';
$format5 = '< name> %s < /name>< age> %d < /age>';


echo 'FORMAT 1: ';
echo sprintf($format1, $name, $age);

echo '<br>';

echo 'FORMAT 2: ';
echo sprintf($format2, $name, $age);

echo '<br>';

echo 'FORMAT 3: ';
echo sprintf($format3, $name, $age);

echo '<br>';

echo 'FORMAT 4: ';
echo sprintf($format4, $name, $age);

echo '<br>';
echo '<br>';

echo 'FORMAT 5: ';
echo sprintf($format5, $name, $age);

?>
```

Comment: I can't replicate your results; both CLI and in a browser (view source to see actual results) display the expected output. Are you showing all of the code you're using in your testing?

Comment: @Prix - Adding <pre></pre> tags only changes the font.

Comment: @newfurniturey - In your tests then, was Format 2 the same as Format 5? The only difference between those in my code is the spaces that follow the less than character.  The only code I am not showing is the echo for each individual format. Those are correct though, just changing the format variable to $format1, $format2 etc...

Comment: @karol 2 and 5 are the same except for the spaces immediately after each `<`. Also, 4 is *not* a blank line - it's the full line with values substituted in.

Comment: @newfurniturey - I added the complete code. I gave my coworker my complete code as above, and he is getting the same results as I am on a different computer, although I am running my code on a virtual machine with a different version of PHP. His is 5.2.5, mine is 5.3.8 .  Could it be a something with the php.ini settings? (p.s. I am a noob, all your help is greatly appreciated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand the issue; to fully clarify what I'm thinking: you're directly looking at the results of the `sprintf()` outputs in a browser - not through View Source mode *or* via Command Line but literally "as it displays".

This explains your results. Let's take Format #2 for example:

```
<name> %s </name><age> %d </age>
```

If you take this exact line of text and save it in a file named `test.html` and open it in a web-browser, you will see:

```
%s %d
```

This is because the browser interprets `<name>` and `<age>` as HTML tags and will not display them textually.

The same can be applied to Format #4 and why it "doesn't display at all". The first `<name` tag doesn't end so the browser assumes all of the text in that line are attributes belonging to said tag.

For all of the above, if you "View Source" on the page you're looking at - you'll see the correct output that you'd expect/want to see.

If your intent is to actually see a textual representation of the output, such as `<name>Lame</name>`, you can use PHP's [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) on each of the outputs:

```
echo 'FORMAT 2: ';
echo htmlentities(sprintf($format2, $name, $age));
echo '<br />';
```

These functions will "convert applicable characters to HTML". In this specific case, `<` and `>` are the important ones =]

Comment: Thank you for explaining why this is happening. I wrote the sprintf outputs to a file and everything is as it should be.  All is right with the world once again...D'oh!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to wrap you strings in `htmlspecialchars()`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

That function will automatically convert your html symbols into encoded equivalents to be displayed on a web page.